# Missing libGL on Fedora, cannot install it

Tags: fedora, nvidia, graphics, opengl

**Problem**

After a recent system update (on Fedora 25) I have some problems with my graphics card (GeForce 1060, using the proprietary driver from RPM Fusion), so I wanted to get diagnostics information using `glxinfo`.

However, `glxinfo` can't find `libGL`:

```
glxinfo: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**What I've tried**

Using DNF, I found out that `mesa-libGL` contains the missing file:

```
$ dnf repoquery -l mesa-libGL

/usr/lib/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/libGL.so.1.2.0
/usr/lib/libGLX_mesa.so.0
/usr/lib/libGLX_mesa.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib64/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib64/libGL.so.1.2.0
/usr/lib64/libGLX_mesa.so.0
/usr/lib64/libGLX_mesa.so.0.0.0
```

This package was already installed but no `libGL.so.*` exists anywhere on the system and reinstalling the package with `dnf reinstall` didn't help either (`find / -name libGL.so.*` doesn't output anything).

**Question**

Why isn't `libGL.so.*` installed? Could it have something to do with the Nvidia driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. `dnf repoquery -l mesa-libGL` outputs the files of all package versions. In this case, `libGL.so.1` is only included in `mesa-libGL-12.0.3-3.fc25.i686`, which is not the version I have installed. Apparently, the package authors changed some dependencies and `libGL.so.1` is now part of `libglvnd-glx`:

```
$ dnf repoquery -l libglvnd-glx.x86_64

/usr/lib64/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib64/libGL.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib64/libGLX.so.0
/usr/lib64/libGLX.so.0.0.0
```

After reinstalling the package, `glxinfo` works again.